# How to create a flow layout in SVG using D3.js?

Tags: svg, d3.js

Say that I have an SVG container with a couple of shapes:

```
<svg>
    <g class="container">
        <rect id="first" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="red" />
        <rect id="second" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="green" />
        <rect id="third" x="200" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="blue" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Using D3 I will manipulate the width of these shapes, for example in transitions. How do I make sure that the rects will always stay in this order, without any space between them? That is, if I modify the `width` of `first`, `x` of `second` and `third` will update instantaneously.

Answer (score 2):

**Option A:** Create a [treemap](http://bl.ocks.org/4063582) and set the sticky option to true: `.sticky(true)`. The treemap layout provides you with x, y, width, and heigth values that you can use to manipulate your DOM/SVG. The sticky option takes care of smooth transitions.

**Option B**: Use plain html elements, such as `div` instead of `svg:rect` elements. If you really just manipulate the width, that should be the more reasonable option:

```
<style>
    #container div{ float: left; }
</style>
<div id="container">
    <div id="first"  style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:red;"   ></div>
    <div id="second" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:green;" ></div>
    <div id="third"  style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:blue;"  ></div>
</div>
```

Using plain html you can manipulate the width and the browser's layout/CSS engine handles the floating. D3 is not restricted to SVG, it can also handle normal html elements (the [treemap example](http://bl.ocks.org/4063582) also uses `div` elements).

**Btw:** In d3 you should not manipulate the DOM directly. Always think of the underlying data and make the updates data driven, i.e., when using a treemap you would the set the `item.value` of a data `item` in your source data, e.g.:

```
data = [ {value: 100}, {value:200}, {value:100} ]
//...
updateData() //changes some values in your data
drawChart()  //draws the whole chart based on the data, e.g., computes the x, y,
             //width, height from the `item.value` (e.g., via d3.layout.treemap)
             //and manipulates/animates the DOM via d3
```

Answer (score 2):

I did a variation of a tree layout to make it into a flow layout.  You can see the [demo here](http://billdwhite.com/wordpress/wp-content/js/flowtree_02.html) and view the [Gist here](http://bl.ocks.org/billdwhite/6929178).